# Can't input (č ć š ž đ ) in python 2.7.x console

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-idle

So , I've searching trough internet and it is so frustrating. When I try to search I get explanations on how to unicode decode and encode files. But I'm not interested in that. I know this is possible since I was able to do that. I don't know what happened. Also, I've tried reinstalling python. Changing the options under the configure IDLE etc. On my laptop there are no problems at all. I can do this:

```
>> a = 'ć'
>>
>> print a
>> ć
```

And on my PC I get:

```
 >> a = 'ć'
 >> Unsupported characters in input
```

I repeat, I'm not talking about encoding in the program. I'm talking about Python console, and it works on my laptop and worked on my previous machines. There's got to be a solution to this issue.

Also, take look at this:

```
>>> a = u'ç'
>>> a
u'\xe7'
>>> print a
ç
>>> a = u'ć'
Unsupported characters in input

>>>
```

Comment: the windows console does not support that ... idle does and most ide's do however have consoles that support that

Comment: Sure that's Python 2.7 on your laptop?

Comment: Are you running Python 2 in one and Python 3 in another?  What happens when you try `a = u'ç'`?

Comment: I am using IDLE console. And yeah, I'm 101% sure there is Python 2.7 on my laptop.

Comment: @Ajean

     >>> a = u'ç'
     >>> a
     u'\xe7'
     >>> print a
     ç
     >>> a = u'ć'
     Unsupported characters in input
     >>>

Comment: The question marked as duplicate, [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console), does **not** address this specific issue. The IDLE window supports full Unicode, unlike the Windows console, but the error is generated by IDLE itself (not Python). I have the same problem and I've tried mightily to solve it, without success. Python 3's IDLE does not have the same issue.

Comment: @Mark ah, my mistake indeed.

Comment: If you are using non-ascii unicode chars, you best upgrade to the most recent 3.x that you can, which have many fixes for working with unicode.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows console is limited in what it can display. You can change the code page using the old DOS `CHCP` command.

```
CHCP 65001
```

This will change the code page to UTF-8, and make the console more relaxed. You will probably see a square instead of the actual character, but at least you won't see an error.

Comment: The problem is with the IDLE console, not Windows console. This will have no effect.

Comment: The Idle Shell can accept and display any character in the Basic Multilingual plane because the same is true of tcl/tk.  This is much better than the Windows console.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy true on the display part but false on the accept.

Comment: @MarkRansom for 2.x, correct.  3.4 does accept, for instance, 'ć' pasted in.  I should have been specific given that the question is about 2.7.

Answer (score -3):

Try to:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
...
```

Comment: **Please** don't cargo cult. You should **never** alter the Python default encoding; there is a *very good reason* that the function is removed from `sys`. Altering the default encoding is like ignoring having broken your leg by strapping a stick to it and keeping on walking rather than to go to a doctor to have the bone set properly.

Comment: This is apart from the fact that doing this *does not solve the issue at hand*.